# SAPUI5 Planning Calendar with Drag and Drop functionality using OData Model V2 (sap.m.planningcalendar)

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to develop a Fiori app using sap.m.planningcalendar control. My default model is ODataModel.V2 which I provide from SAP backend. Everything seemed to be normal until I decided to implement DnD functionality which comes with ui5 version 1.56.

The [sample](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendarDnD/code/Page.controller.js) has an example code like below;

```js
handleAppointmentDropBetweenRows = function () {
    var aPath = oAppBindingContext.getPath().split("/"),
        iIndex = aPath.pop(),
        sRowAppointmentsPath = aPath.join("/");

    oRowBindingContext.getObject().appointments.push(
        oModel.getProperty(oAppBindingContext.getPath())
    );

    oModel.getProperty(sRowAppointmentsPath).splice(iIndex, 1);
};
```

This is not working in my case. So instead, i am adding new appointment;

**oCalendarRow.addAppointment(oAppointment);**

Although, if I create a new JSON model and set the data, this is working fine, but if I use the OData.v2 model coming from the backend as the default model, it throws an error like below;

> Error: adding element with duplicate id '__appointment0-__row0-__xmlview0--PC1-0-96'*

[Error-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tztoj.jpg)

I couldn't find any example for sap.m.planningcalendar with a backend scenario with drag&drop functionality.

So any suggestions ?

P.S : I have also tried adding **templateShareable: 'false'** for PlanningCalendarRows in the view like below;

```
appointments="{path : 'to_MaintOrderOper', templateShareable: 'false'}"
```

Also didn't work.

Best regards

My view;

```
<mvc:View controllerName="ZPM.ZPM_CAPACITY_PLAN.controller.Main" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:unified="sap.ui.unified" xmlns:modeltype="sap.ui.model.type" xmlns="sap.m">
<App id="idAppControl">
    <pages>
        <Page title="{i18n>title}">
            <content>
                <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
                    <PlanningCalendar id="PC1" rows="{path: '/ZPM_C_CAPACITY_PLAN2', parameters:{expand:'to_MaintOrderOper'}, templateShareable: 'false'}" appointmentsVisualization="Filled"
                        appointmentSelect="handleAppointmentSelect">
                        <toolbarContent>
                            <Title text="{i18n>toolbarTitle}" titleStyle="H4"/>
                            <ToolbarSpacer/>
                            <Button 
                                id="saveButton" 
                                text="{i18n>save}" 
                                type="Emphasized" 
                                icon="sap-icon://save" 
                                press="handleSaveChanges" 
                                tooltip="{i18n>submit}"/>
                            <Label text="Logged in as"/>
                            <Select 
                                    id="userRole" 
                                    change="handleRoleChange" 
                                    selectedKey="admin" 
                                    width="230px">
                                <items>
                                    <core:Item key="admin" text="Admin"/>
                                    <core:Item key="manager" text="Manager"/>
                                    <core:Item key="donna" text="Donna Moore"/>
                                </items>
                            </Select>
                        </toolbarContent>
                        <rows>
                            <PlanningCalendarRow 
                                    title="{EmployeeFullName}" 
                                    text="{Skill}" 
                                    icon="{EmployeePic}"
                                    enableAppointmentsDragAndDrop="{path:'EmployeeFullName', formatter:'.canModifyAppointments'}"
                                    enableAppointmentsResize="{path:'EmployeeFullName', formatter:'.canModifyAppointments'}" 
                                    appointmentDrop="handleAppointmentDrop"
                                    appointmentDragEnter="handleAppointmentDragEnter"
                                    appointmentResize="handleAppointmentResize" 
                                    appointmentCreate="handleAppointmentCreate"
                                    appointments="{path : 'to_MaintOrderOper', templateShareable: 'false'}">
                                <appointments>
                                    <unified:CalendarAppointment 
                                        startDate="{path: 'StartDateTime2', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTimeOffset'}"
                                        endDate="{path: 'EndDateTime2', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTimeOffset'}" 
                                        icon="{PlanningIcon}" 
                                        title="{Title}" 
                                        text="{Info}">
                                    </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                                </appointments>
                            </PlanningCalendarRow>
                        </rows>
                    </PlanningCalendar>
                </VBox>
            </content>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

Also my controller;

```
/*eslint-disable*/
```

sap.ui.define(['jquery.sap.global',
        'sap/m/MessageBox',
        'sap/m/Button',
        'sap/m/Dialog',
        'sap/m/Label',
        'sap/m/Popover',
        'sap/m/List',
        'sap/m/StandardListItem',
        'sap/ui/core/Fragment',
        'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
        'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel',
        'sap/m/MessageToast'
    ],

```
function (jQuery, MessageBox, Button, Dialog, Label, Popover, List, StandardListItem, Fragment, Controller, JSONModel, MessageToast) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("ZPM.ZPM_CAPACITY_PLAN.controller.Main", {

        onInit: function () {


        },

        toDateObject: function (sDateString) {

            var oAppointmentDate = new Date(sDateString);
            return oAppointmentDate;

        },

        roles: {
            donna: "Donna Moore",
            manager: "manager",
            admin: "admin"
        },

        handleRoleChange: function () {
            this.getView().getModel().refresh(true);
        },

        getUserRole: function () {
            return this.roles[this.byId("userRole").getSelectedKey()];
        },

        canModifyAppointments: function (sRole) {
            var sUserRole = this.getUserRole();

            if (sUserRole === this.roles.manager || sUserRole === this.roles.admin || sUserRole === sRole) {
                return true;
            }
        },

        // New functionality to show detailed popover for Jobs

        handleAppointmentSelect: function (oEvent) {
            debugger;
            var oJobDetails = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            var oAppointment = oEvent.getParameter("appointment");
            var oTitle = oAppointment.getTitle();
            var oIcon = oAppointment.getIcon();
            var oStartDateText = this._oResourceBundle().getText("startDate");
            var oStartDate = oAppointment.getStartDate();
            var oEndDateText = this._oResourceBundle().getText("endDate");
            var oEndDate = oAppointment.getEndDate();
            var oJobInfoText = this._oResourceBundle().getText("jobInfo");
            var oJobInfo = oAppointment.getText();
            var mJobDetails = {
                pages: [{
                    pageId: "jobDetailsPageId",
                    title: oTitle,
                    icon: oIcon,
                    groups: [{
                        elements: [{
                            label: oStartDateText,
                            value: oStartDate
                        }, {
                            label: oEndDateText,
                            value: oEndDate
                        }, {
                            label: oJobInfoText,
                            value: oJobInfo
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            };

            // set the data for the model
            oJobDetails.setData(mJobDetails);
            // Now open QuickView
            this.openQuickView(oAppointment, oJobDetails);
        },

        openQuickView: function (oAppointment, oJobDetails) {
            this.createPopover();

            this._oQuickView.setModel(oJobDetails, "oJobDetailsModel");

            this._oQuickView.openBy(oAppointment);

        },

        createPopover: function () {
            if (this._oQuickView) {
                this._oQuickView.destroy();
            }
            this._oQuickView = sap.ui.xmlfragment("ZPM.ZPM_CAPACITY_PLAN.view.JobDetails", this);
            this.getView().addDependent(this._oQuickView);
        },

        handleAppointmentDragEnter: function (oEvent) {
            if (this.isAppointmentOverlap(oEvent, oEvent.getParameter("calendarRow"))) {
                oEvent.preventDefault();
            }
        },

        onQuickviewClose: function (oEvent) {
            if (this._oQuickView) {
                this._oQuickView.destroy();
            }
            //oEvent.getParameters().openBy.setSelected(false);
        },

        handleAppointmentDrop: function (oEvent) {
            debugger;
            var oAppointment = oEvent.getParameter("appointment"),
                oStartDate = oEvent.getParameter("startDate"),
                oEndDate = oEvent.getParameter("endDate"),
                oCalendarRow = oEvent.getParameter("calendarRow"),
                bCopy = oEvent.getParameter("copy"),
                oModel = this.getView().getModel(),
                oAppBindingContext = oAppointment.getBindingContext(),
                oRowBindingContext = oCalendarRow.getBindingContext();


            /*  handleAppointmentDropBetweenRows = function () {
                    var aPath = oAppBindingContext.getPath().split("/"),
                        iIndex = aPath.pop(),
                        sRowAppointmentsPath = aPath.join("/");
                    oCalendarRow.addAppointment(oAppointment)

                    oRowBindingContext.getObject().appointments.push(
                        oModel.getProperty(oAppBindingContext.getPath())
                    );

                    oModel.getProperty(sRowAppointmentsPath).splice(iIndex, 1);
                };*/

            if (bCopy) { // "copy" appointment
                var oProps = jQuery.extend({}, oModel.getProperty(oAppointment.getBindingContext().getPath()));
                oProps.start = oStartDate;
                oProps.end = oEndDate;

                oRowBindingContext.getObject().appointments.push(oProps);
            } else { // "move" appointment
                //oModel.setProperty("start", oStartDate, oAppBindingContext);
                //oModel.setProperty("end", oEndDate, oAppBindingContext);
                oAppointment.setStartDate(oStartDate);
                oAppointment.setEndDate(oEndDate);
                oAppointment.setType("Type03");

                if (oAppointment.getParent() !== oCalendarRow) {
                    debugger;
                    oCalendarRow.addAppointment(oAppointment);
                    //handleAppointmentDropBetweenRows();
                }
            }


            MessageToast.show(oCalendarRow.getTitle() + "'s '" + "Appointment '" + oAppointment.getTitle() + "' now starts at \n" + oStartDate +
                "\n and end at \n" + oEndDate + ".");
        },

        handleAppointmentResize: function (oEvent) {
            var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
            var oAppointment = oEvent.getParameter("appointment"),
                oStartDate = oEvent.getParameter("startDate"),
                oEndDate = oEvent.getParameter("endDate");
            var dateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({pattern : "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" });   
            if (!this.isAppointmentOverlap(oEvent, oAppointment.getParent())) {
                MessageToast.show("Appointment '" + oAppointment.getTitle() + "' now starts at \n" + oStartDate + "\n and end at \n" + oEndDate +
                    ".");
                //  oModel.setProperty("StartDateTime2", dateFormat.format(oStartDate) , oAppointment.getBindingContext());
                //  oModel.setProperty("EndDateTime2", dateFormat.format(oEndDate) , oAppointment.getBindingContext());

                oAppointment.setStartDate(oStartDate);
                oAppointment.setEndDate(oEndDate);
                oAppointment.setType("Type03");
            } else {
                MessageToast.show("As a manager you can not resize events if they overlap with another events");
            }
        },
        // Our App should not support Appointment Creation

        /*handleAppointmentCreate: function (oEvent) {
            var oStartDate = oEvent.getParameter("startDate"),
                oEndDate = oEvent.getParameter("endDate"),
                oPlanningCalendarRow = oEvent.getParameter("calendarRow"),
                oModel = this.getView().getModel(),
                sPath = oPlanningCalendarRow.getBindingContext().getPath();

            oModel.getProperty(sPath).appointments.push({
                title: "New Appointment",
                start: oStartDate,
                end: oEndDate
            });

            MessageToast.show("New Appointment is created at \n" + oStartDate + "\n and end at \n" + oEndDate + ".");

            oModel.refresh(true);
        },*/

        isAppointmentOverlap: function (oEvent, oCalendarRow) {
            var oAppointment = oEvent.getParameter("appointment"),
                oStartDate = oEvent.getParameter("startDate"),
                oEndDate = oEvent.getParameter("endDate"),
                bAppointmentOverlapped;

            if (this.getUserRole() === this.roles.manager) {
                bAppointmentOverlapped = oCalendarRow.getAppointments().some(function (oCurrentAppointment) {
                    if (oCurrentAppointment === oAppointment) {
                        return;
                    }

                    var oAppStartTime = oCurrentAppointment.getStartDate().getTime(),
                        oAppEndTime = oCurrentAppointment.getEndDate().getTime();

                    if (oAppStartTime <= oStartDate.getTime() && oStartDate.getTime() < oAppEndTime) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (oAppStartTime < oEndDate.getTime() && oEndDate.getTime() <= oAppEndTime) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (oStartDate.getTime() <= oAppStartTime && oAppStartTime < oEndDate.getTime()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }

            return bAppointmentOverlapped;
        },

        handleSaveChanges: function (oEvent) {

            var oModel = this.getView().getModel(),
                bError = false;


            // abort if the  model has not been changed
            if (!oModel.hasPendingChanges()) {
                var bCompact = !!this.getView().$().closest(".sapUiSizeCompact").length;
                MessageBox.information(
                    this._oResourceBundle().getText("noChangesMessage"), {
                        styleClass: bCompact ? "sapUiSizeCompact" : ""
                    }
                );
                return;
            }

            oModel.submitChanges();


        },

        _checkIfBatchRequestSucceeded: function (oEvent) {
            var oParams = oEvent.getParameters();
            var aRequests = oEvent.getParameters().requests;
            var oRequest;
            if (oParams.success) {
                if (aRequests) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < aRequests.length; i++) {
                        oRequest = oEvent.getParameters().requests[i];
                        if (!oRequest.success) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },

        _fnUpdateSuccess: function () {
            this.getView().setBusy(false);
            this.getView().unbindObject();
            this.getRouter().getTargets().display("object");

        },

        _oResourceBundle: function() {

            var oBundle = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
            return oBundle;

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe it would help for clarification, if you show us your xml view and your controller file, where you use your oData model.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I have edited my question as per your request.

Comment: The error message “Error: adding element with duplicate id '__appointment0-__row0-__xmlview0--PC1-0-96'*” says that something is trying to be created,
which was existing before and that one is not destroyed.
This cannot be related with the drag and drop itself, but might be the consequence of some drag and drop event handlers.